# After upgrading my nexus 4 to 4.3, adb in not recognizing it

Tags: eclipse, adb, android-4.3-jelly-bean, nexus-4

My device driver for nexus 4 is not installing on my windows, after trying several times.
My sdk tools and platform tools are updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same thing, i'm using windows 7 btw.

**On your phone:**

1) Connect your Nexus 4 to your pc with usb

2) Revoke USB debugging authorizations

**On Windows**

1) In windows go to your device manager (called MTP for my case)

2) Uninstall the current driver

3) Re-install the driver from disk (\extras\google\usb_driver)

In my case the device was visible again in Eclipse, and after authorizing it on my phone I was able to use it like before. Hope this helps

Comment: In my case, I just updated the driver searching the folder you've mentioned.